# Sign key in request header

Tags: python, request, web-crawler

I was hitting one website through script

```
headers = {
    'Host': 'appgateway.lifekh.com',
    'user-agent': 'WOWNOW/2.13.0 (Android)',   
    'termtyp': 'ANDROID',
    'deviceid': '82729F302557F0FDF20389D6941BF46BCA2957E8',
    'deviceinfo': '',
    'phonemodel': 'samsung SM-J210F',
    'signver': '1.0',
    'sign': '1bf6fc40637919e2f3a9955bea86387b',
    'requesttm': '202105271833098494',
    'accept-language': 'en-US',
    'appversion': '2.13.0',
    'channel': 'GooglePlay',
    'appid': 'SuperApp',
    'appno': '10',
    'projectname': 'SuperApp',
    'accesstoken': '',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
}

data = '{"pageNum":"2","businessScope":"","isNew":false,"sortType":"","marketingTypes":[],"location":{"lat":11.565687,"lon":104.890678},"pageSize":"8"}'

response = requests.post('https://appgateway.lifekh.com/gateway_web/takeaway-merchant/app/super-app/nearby', headers=headers, data=data)
print response.content
```

for each request the sing key was keep changing in the website header
how they are generating sign key is there any encoding format

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what it is that you wanna do.

Comment: @NovusEdge i updated
want to know how 'sign' in header was generating

Comment: I believe that the `sign` header is unique to the request and randomized, I can't say for sure, but if you wanna know how it was generated, you can try looking into the API docs for the host you are sending requests to.